# Can't access ivar CGPDFPageRef

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, variables, cgpdfdocument

I can't access the CGPDFPageRef and CGPDFDocumentRef of my ReaderControllerView from my ContentViewController. I declared them under `@public` in my header file like this:

```
@interface ReaderContentPage : UIView{
  @public
    CGPDFDocumentRef _PDFDocRef;
    CGPDFPageRef _PDFPageRef;
```

And I try to access them like this:

```
ReaderControllerView *theReader = [ReaderControllerView alloc]init];

theReader._PDFPageRef //OR
theReader._PDFDocRef
```

It will not show up. However, I can access the other iVars with no problem whatsoever. So it really bugs me why can't I access the two variables. Anyone can tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you declared `CGPDFDocumentRef _PDFDocRef; CGPDFPageRef _PDFPageRef` these variables in `ReaderContentPage` class and trying to access them by creating object of `ReaderControllerView` class how is it possible?

Comment: lol yeah he must have either typed it wrong or got the concepts wrong..!